# Material UI Tooltip Component overwriting className on children components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

[Example Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-ig3mb?file=/src/index.js)

There are three buttons visible.

The first of which has no tooltip, and changes colour based on state and hover.
The second has a tooltip, and the className is being overwritten, which results in the wrong colours being displayed.
The third simply has the props re-ordered in the child component to solve the problem.

My question: Is this the expected behaviour? Do I really have to make `className` the last prop so that it actually gets used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Material UI, you generally have to follow their recommendation for styling your components. One of which is to [Override Style with classes prop](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes)

```
const StatusButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { classes, status, ...rest } = props;

  return (
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
      size="small"
      classes={{root: classes[status]}} // this was previously className prop
      ref={ref}
      {...rest}
    >
      <CloseIcon fontSize="small" className={classes.actionIcon} />
      {status}
    </Button>
  );
});
```

[image: Edit React Functional Component (forked)]